# Русская ЕДА

Tags: этимология

Есть ли в древних языках, скажем, греческом, латинском слова-основы, которые могли бы исторически дать это самое русское слово ЕДА?

А так же: существуют ли в современных западно-европейских языках слова, родственные русскому ЕДА?

Answer (score 4):

Да, в латыни глагол есть звучал как edere, а съедобный был ediblis. После этого будет понятным, что тот же корень был и в германских языках, например в немецком essen, в английском eat. Сходно звучал этот корень и в санскрите эдак 3 тыс. лет назад. Какие еще нужны доказательства, что русский язык - индоевропейский?

Comment: По я не спрашивал о доказательствах русского, как ИЕ-го языка. Об этом речь впереди. Раз уж именно Вы мне ответили, за что Вам благодарность и мое голосование, не могли бы открыться - как Вы узнали о том, что только-что написали?

Answer (score 2):

В санскрите: 
adya I (pn. от ad)
1) съедобный, поедаемый;
2) n пища.

В арабском غذاء - еда, так и звучит.   Это индоевропейский?

Comment: Хороший вопрос!

Ни "ваш" арабский, ни турецкий, который сейчас Вам приведу, не считаются  индоевропейскими. Скажем, в узбекском языке русский глагол ЕШЬ переводится как Е.  А слово ЕДА не имеет к нему никакого (корневого)  отношения. 

Так же и в турецком есть своя "забава". Если по-турецки ЕШЬ это yemek, то слово ЕДА это gıda (фонетически по сути та же ЕДА).

Понятно, что "родственников" к ЕДЕ (ЕШЬ) в разных языках должно быть много. Этимология почему-то поленилась это досконально рассмотреть.

Comment: Это вы поленились прочитать и досконально разобраться. Понятно, что заполошничать проще, г-н проф.языковед.

Comment: вы плохо искали:  в узбекском  жевать-yutadi, в таджикском-хоидан

Comment: узб. yutadi - скорее съест, будет есть.

Answer (score 0):

Еда - от праиндоевропейского корня ***e̯ed-*** "есть, кушать".